# Struggling to get session delete route to work with Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm creating an application which will also enable third party sites to authenticate against it's user database.  I'm using Devise and have added an API namespace to my routes in the following way (this will change as I go further as I'll add more routes to the API):

```
  devise_scope :user do
    resources :users
    put 'change_plan', :to => 'users#change_plan'
    namespace :api, constraints: { format: :json } do
      resources :sessions, :only => [:create, :destroy]
    end  
  end
```

I'm overriding the Devise controllers for my sessions and have the following for the destroy action:

```
def destroy
  resource = User.find_by_authentication_token(params[:auth_token]||request.headers["X-AUTH-TOKEN"])
  resource.authentication_token = nil
  resource.save
  sign_out(resource_name)
  render :json => {:message => "User signed-out"}.to_json, :status => :ok
end
```

When testing the API using Postman, I can get the create route (and all others in the application that respond to JSON) to work perfectly and return the right results.  However, I just cannot get the DELETE route to work no matter what I try.  I've been through about ten tutorials and tried alternatives based on them, all of which give me a variation of the following error: No route matches [DELETE] "/"

I've also tried variations like using "match" which works fine for creating the session and generating the token but not for delete.  I've also tried every URL combination / variation I can think of in Postman with no luck.  At this stage I'm wondering if there is a bug in something like Postman / Devise or if I've missed something very elementary (most likely!?).  Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Further info - rake routes for sessions are as follows:
api_sessions POST     /api/sessions(.:format) api/sessions#create {:format=>:json}

api_session DELETE   /api/sessions/:id(.:format) api/sessions#destroy {:format=>:json}

Not sure if it's useful but routes relating to overridden Devise controller for users (resource) are as follows:

users GET      /users(.:format)                                 users#index
                         POST     /users(.:format)                                 users#create
                new_user GET      /users/new(.:format)                             users#new
               edit_user GET      /users/:id/edit(.:format)                        users#edit
                    user GET      /users/:id(.:format)                             users#show
                         PATCH    /users/:id(.:format)                             users#update
                         PUT      /users/:id(.:format)                             users#update
                         DELETE   /users/:id(.:format)                             users#destroy

Comment: Can you show the result of your `rake routes` ?

Comment: What's the route you're using to log in? I'd suspect it's something different than the root path "/", and judging from the `No route matches [DELETE] "/"`, you're using "/" to log out. Seems weird to me.

Comment: Many thanks for your replies.  @SunnyK - have added a summary of routes, hope this helps (there are loads more but I've just included those for the session and users).

Comment: @awendt - I'm using /api/sessions to login and have tried just about every variation of that (using DELETE method) to logout but with no luck.